.NET Core encryption padding is invalid and cannot be removed
I'm trying to work with encrypt / decrypt in an ASP.NET Core Web API project. I found this article showing a working example to both encrypt and decrypt:
https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/encrypt-decrypt-string-asp-net-core
Copied and ran, it worked, great -- so far.
Then I changed the string to encrypt/decrypt and if failed with padding issue not allowed. The EncryptString and DecryptString methods were verbatim to the website source code.
// THIS IS ORIGINAL and works (without Console.WriteLine)
var content = "Example test";
var key = "E546C8DF278CD5931069B522E695D4F2";
var encrypted = EncryptString(content, key);
var decrypted = DecryptString(encrypted, key);

// Then I changed to encrypt a simple string and fails
content = "testing16charsX1";
encrypted = EncryptString(content, key);
decrypted = DecryptString(encrypted, key);

Original code for functions to keep in single source location here.
public static string EncryptString(string text, string keyString)
{
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);

    using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        using (var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(key, aesAlg.IV))
        {
            using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.Write(text);
                }

                var iv = aesAlg.IV;

                var decryptedContent = msEncrypt.ToArray();

                var result = new byte[iv.Length + decryptedContent.Length];

                Buffer.BlockCopy(iv, 0, result, 0, iv.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(decryptedContent, 0, result, iv.Length, decryptedContent.Length);

                return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static string DecryptString(string cipherText, string keyString)
{
    var fullCipher = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

    var iv = new byte[16];
    var cipher = new byte[16];

    Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, iv.Length);

    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);

    using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        using (var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(key, iv))
        {
            string result;

            using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipher))
            {
                using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                     using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                     {
                         result = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                     }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}

Appreciate the help. Additionally, would like to enforce encryption / decryption to AES256 and nothing in here about the KeySize set to 256, but wanted to test without breaking, but appears to be broken out-the-gate too?

A better reference is the AES class documentation. Converting to BASE64 or any other encoding isn't part of encryption and should be kept out of the encryption methods.

All algorithms derived from SymmetricAlgorithm have a settable KeySize property.

Here's the mistake. In the EncryptString method, it sequentially copies the IV and encrypted content:
var result = new byte[iv.Length + decryptedContent.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(iv, 0, result, 0, iv.Length);
Buffer.BlockCopy(decryptedContent, 0, result, iv.Length, decryptedContent.Length);

But in the DecryptString method, it only copies 16 bytes of encrypted content:
var iv = new byte[16];
var cipher = new byte[16];
Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);
Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, iv.Length);

It should copy all the remaining content:
var cipher = new byte[fullCipher.Length - iv.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(fullCipher, iv.Length, cipher, 0, cipher.Length);

The default padding mode of AES is pkcs7, and if your input data length is exactly BlockSize, an additional block will be appended. If you want to enforce the encrypted content length to 16, you need to change the padding mode to None and manually pad the input data.
